# Unable to check existing XML nodes in Adobe Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex

I am getting an XML data from server (please refer to xmlData value).
I need to:

1. Create another XML with non-duplicates Folders
2. Create another XML with final count on monthly basis.

I am unable to do this with below code and getting duplicate records.

```
  private var xmlData:XML = new XML("<root><SUMMARY_RECORD><FOLDER>Folder1</FOLDER><COUNT>100</COUNT><MONTH>Feb</MONTH><QUARTER>Q1</QUARTER><YEAR>2014</YEAR></SUMMARY_RECORD><SUMMARY_RECORD><FOLDER>Folder1</FOLDER><COUNT>100</COUNT><MONTH>Feb</MONTH><QUARTER>Q1</QUARTER><YEAR>2014</YEAR></SUMMARY_RECORD></root>");

    var folderDataXML:XML = new XML("<root></root>");
    var folderDGDataXML:XML = new XML("<root></root>");

    private function loaded():void{
        var item:XML;
        folderDGDataXML.appendChild(new XML("<FOLDER_NAME><Name>ALL</Name></FOLDER_NAME>"));
        for each (item in xmlData.SUMMARY_RECORD){
            if (folderDGDataXML.FOLDER_NAME.(Name==item.FOLDER).toString() == ""){
                folderDGDataXML.appendChild(new XML("<FOLDER_NAME><Name>"+item.FOLDER+"</Name></FOLDER_NAME>"));
            }   

            if (folderDataXML.SUMMARY_RECORD.(Name==item.MONTH).toXMLString() == ""){
                folderDataXML.appendChild(new XML("<SUMMARY_RECORD><Name>"+item.MONTH+"</Name><COUNT>"+item.COUNT+"</COUNT></SUMMARY_RECORD>"));
            }else{
                var count:int = Number(folderDataXML.SUMMARY_RECORD.(Name==item.MONTH).COUNT) + Number(item.COUNT);
                folderDataXML.SUMMARY_RECORD.(Name==item.MONTH).COUNT = count;
            }

        }
    }
```

Final output, **folderDGDataXML**:

```
<root>
  <FOLDER_NAME>
    <Name>ALL</Name>
  </FOLDER_NAME>
  <FOLDER_NAME>
    <Name>Folder1</Name>
  </FOLDER_NAME>
  <FOLDER_NAME>
    <Name>Folder1</Name>
  </FOLDER_NAME>
</root>
```

**folderDataXML**:

```
<root>
  <SUMMARY_RECORD>
    <Name>Feb</Name>
    <COUNT>100</COUNT>
  </SUMMARY_RECORD>
  <SUMMARY_RECORD>
    <Name>Feb</Name>
    <COUNT>100</COUNT>
  </SUMMARY_RECORD>
</root>
```

What am I doing wrong?
After getting correct XML, I need to populate datagrid & column chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

In XML Checking the elements present or not with `hasOwnProperty` or we can use `in` operator anyhow our case if it is based on value try like this way `folderDGDataXML.descendants("FOLDER_NAME").(Name.text() == "Folder1");` //Return always XMLList. With the help of length() we can predict element with value occur or not.

Hope this will work for you.

```
var xmlData:XML = new XML("<root><SUMMARY_RECORD><FOLDER>Folder1</FOLDER><COUNT>100</COUNT><MONTH>Feb</MONTH><QUARTER>Q1</QUARTER><YEAR>2014</YEAR></SUMMARY_RECORD><SUMMARY_RECORD><FOLDER>Folder1</FOLDER><COUNT>100</COUNT><MONTH>Feb</MONTH><QUARTER>Q1</QUARTER><YEAR>2014</YEAR></SUMMARY_RECORD></root>");

var folderDataXML:XML = new XML("<root></root>");
var folderDGDataXML:XML = new XML("<root></root>");
var item:XML;

folderDGDataXML.appendChild(new XML("<FOLDER_NAME><Name>ALL</Name></FOLDER_NAME>"));

for each (item in xmlData.SUMMARY_RECORD)
{
    var folderName:String =  item.FOLDER.text();
    var monthName:String =  item.MONTH.text();

    var existXMLList:XMLList = folderDGDataXML.descendants("FOLDER_NAME").(Name.text() == folderName);

    if (existXMLList.length() == 0)
    {
        folderDGDataXML.appendChild(new XML("<FOLDER_NAME><Name>"+item.FOLDER+"</Name></FOLDER_NAME>"));
    }   

    var monthXMLList:XMLList = folderDataXML.descendants("SUMMARY_RECORD").(Name.text() == monthName);

    if (monthXMLList.length() == 0)
    {
        folderDataXML.appendChild(new XML("<SUMMARY_RECORD><Name>"+item.MONTH+"</Name><COUNT>"+item.COUNT+"</COUNT></SUMMARY_RECORD>"));
    }
    else
    {
        monthXMLList..COUNT = Number(monthXMLList..COUNT) + Number(item.COUNT);
        //If more than one node it throws error. you need to use loop operation

    }

}

trace("folderDGDataXML" + folderDGDataXML);
trace("folderDataXML" + folderDataXML);
```

Comment: Hi Raja,Thanks for the reply. Thanks for the reply. My code worked fine when after changing the element <Name> with another value like : <MONTH>.